# Multiple inputs and outputs, parallelize it using what?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, geopandas

`Pool.map()` accepts only one iterable as an argument, that's not my case, and I find it difficult to reduce it to a single iterable variable.

`mp.Process()` only allows me one variable output, which is not my case either, my outputs are 4 list of geodataframe which is created in the parallelization

with what function (in `multiprocessing`) can I parallelize it?

Comment: what do you want to parallelize? what is the entrance? What should be the way out?

Comment: You can `zip` together the multiple *iterable* arguments and call `Pool.map` with that result as the single *iterable* argument in which case the *func* argument to `map` then will be a function that takes a `tuple` as its argument or you can call `pool.starmap` in which case the *func* argument to `starmap`  will be a function that takes *n* arguments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `zip` together the multiple *iterable* arguments and call `Pool.map` with that result as the single *iterable* argument in which case the *func* argument to `map` then will be a function that takes a `tuple` as its argument or you can call `pool.starmap` in which case the *func* argument to `starmap` will be a function that takes *n* arguments.

This demonstrates the two techniques:

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool

def worker_1(t):
    x, y, z = t # unpack
    ...

def worker_2(x, y, z):
    ...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = Pool()
    results_1 = pool.map(worker_1, zip(range(1, 101), range(2, 102), range(3, 103)))
    results_2 = pool.starmap(worker_2, zip(range(1, 101), range(2, 102), range(3, 103)))
```

Comment: I will try that, now I was trying to use this pool.apply_async, what would be its pro and cons vs pool?

Comment: You mean the pros and cons of  `pool.apply_async` vs. `pool.map` (or `pool.starmap`).  `pool.map` allows you to specify a (or will calculate a suitable) *chunksize* value to be used which for large *iterable* arguments can be more efficient than submitting individual tasks. On the other hand, `map` must always return the results in task-submission order whereas `apply_async`, especially when used with the *callback* argument, allows you to process results as they become available (task completion order).

Comment: I forgot to mention that my inputs and outputs are geodataframe shapely.Polygon and shapely.Point 
```
TypeError: 'Polygon' object is not iterable
```
There are another solution?

Comment: Are these arguments that are constant for every submitted task? You many need to post a *new* question and then add a comment here containing a link to the new question. Be sure to post code this time.

Comment: new question is in
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69254771/parallelize-a-function-with-multiple-inputs-outputs-geodataframe-variables