# Parallelize a function with multiple inputs/outputs geodataframe-variables

Tags: python, parallel-processing, geopandas, pool, shapely

Using a previous answer (merci Booboo),
The code idea is:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def worker_1(x, y, z):
    ...
    t = zip(list_of_Polygon,list_of_Point,column_Point)
return t

def collected_result(t):
    x, y, z = t # unpack
    save_shp("polys.shp",x)
    save_shp("point.shp",y,z)

if __name__ == '__main__':

gg = gpd.read_file("name.shp")
pool = Pool()
for index, pol in gg.iterrows():
    xlon ,ylat = gg.centroid
    result = pool.starmap(worker_1, zip(pol,xlon,ylat))
    # or
    # result = mp.Process(worker_1,args = (pol,xlon,ylat))
    pool.close()
    pool.join()  

collected_result(result)
```

But the geodataframe (Polygon,Point) is not iterable so I can't use pool, any suggestions to parallelize?

How to compress the (geodataframe) outputs in worker_1 and then save them independently (or multiple layers in a shapefile), its better to use global parameters? ... because zip only saves lists (right*)?

Comment: This is not clear. First you have an indentation problem in `worker_1`, Second, `worker_1` will receive a single argument if you are using `map`. Third, What is `MultiPolygon`? Is this an object that is to be reused over and over for all the `lat` and `lon` values? And what is `collected_result` doing in this question? Is `MultiPolygon` some sort of collection? Please update your question with corrections and explanations.

Comment: Just tell me what `MultiPolygon` is. See my previous comment.

Comment: @Booboo In theory it is to enter a multiple shapefile and find the polygons inside, and then do some calculations in worker_1 with output as polygons and points with certain characteristics (calculated in worker_1). In theory collect_result should regroup all outputs without repeating.

For example a shapefile has 1000 polygons, each polygon goes to a processor makes the calculations and saves them in collected

Comment: I guess my question is whether the same `MultiPolygon` object is to be passed to `worker_` for all `x` and `y` values?

Comment: No, it was a way of saying that there were many input polygons, but most polygons in the shapefile are not multipolygon ... so each polygon in the shapefile goes through worker_1 
I modify the code to make it clearer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if I understand what you are trying to do, perhaps the following is what you need. Here I am building up the `args` list that will be used as the *iterable* argument to `starmap` by iterating on `gg.iterrows()` (there is no need to use `zip`):

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool

def worker_1(pol, xlon, ylat):
    ...
    t = zip(list_of_Polygon, list_of_Point, column_Point)
    return t

def collected_result(t):
    x, y, z = t # unpack
    save_shp("polys.shp", x)
    save_shp("point.shp", y, z)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    gg = gpd.read_file("name.shp")
    pool = Pool()
    args = []
    for index, pol in gg.iterrows():
        xlon, ylat = gg.centroid
        args.append((pol, xlon, ylat))
    result = pool.starmap(worker_1, args)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()      
    collected_result(result)
```

You were creating a single `Pool` instance and in your loop doing repeatedly calls to methods `starmap`, `close` and `join`. But once you call `close` on the `Pool` instance you cannot submit any more tasks to the pool (i.e. call `starmap` again), so I think your looping/indentation was all wrong.

Comment: ok I will correct that ... thanks booboo ^^
PD: I hope I do not get polygon again it is not iterable,

Comment: I just want to make sure that my answer addresses your question correctly.